# How to make redis-server process run in front ground?

Tags: redis

When I run redis by `redis-server CONFIG_FILE`, the process will be run in the background. If I run it without CONFIG_FILE parameter, it will not run in background. How can I make it run in front ground with a configuration file? It is useful when send this command to a docker. The docker container will stop running if the process is running in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set daemonize to 'no' in your CONFIG_FILE.